# NCHAR(916) in sql String

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to put the nchar character Δ in a string like this:

```
SET @ANALISE1 =

 'SELECT 
  * 
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
    ''*'' Codigo,
    ''Total'' Descricao,
    SUM(#DADOS_VISTA_PRODUTO.[Mês||Volume]) [Mês||'+@MESATUAL+'Ton],
    SUM(#DADOS_VISTA_PRODUTO.[Mês||Mês Anterior Volume]) [Mês||'+ @MESANTERIOR +' Ton],
    (((SUM(#DADOS_VISTA_PRODUTO.[Mês||Volume])/SUM(#DADOS_VISTA_PRODUTO.[Mês||Mês Anterior Volume])) -1) * 100)
    [Mês||'+ **NCHAR(916)**+'%A]
  '

EXEC (@ANALISE1)
```

but it appears as a question mark.
Anyone know why?

Comment: Encoding. You need to set the encoding to **UTF-8**.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `@ANALISE1` as a [`varchar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx?ppud=4). Change it to [`nvarchar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) to handle unicode characters.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/708/0)

Comment: Thanks that's could work but my @analise1 has more then 4000 car. so What can i do?

Comment: @She-ra You should use `nvarchar(max)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using ascii and the triangle you are pasting in is unicode

you can read more about character encoding [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)